# NoSuchMethodError on Spring Boot Security

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm following this tutorial : https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-security-autoconfiguration  to add Simple Auth. to my Spring Boot Project. When i try to run my application i always get this error :

> Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(ZLjava/util/function/Supplier;)V

IDK why im getting this or is this related something about Version problem. Do you guys have any idea about this ?

Comment: please add your pom.xml

Comment: You are mixing jars from different versions of Spring or are using an incompatible version of Spring with Spring Security (or vice versa).

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum. I also think that its something related about versions. 
I will deeply look into this problem and try to solve it completely.

For people who is looking answers like me i will post an answer once i found a fix

Comment: add your `pom.xml` to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can relate your question with this answer

pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

security configuration class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class Config extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("username")
            .password("password")
            .roles("ADMIN","USER");
 }

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.cors().and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/greetings").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .and()
            .httpBasic()
            .and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
 }
}
```

A simple restController

```
@GetMapping("/greetings")
public String greetings(){
    return "Hello World!";
}
```

this is the basic security using memory authentication. you can relate your pom.xml and configuration.class, In most cases spring-boot, resolves the versions by default.